# jQuery or JavaScript - set back the focus to a body element once it is in a cross domain iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, click, focus, cross-domain

I am facing the problem, that has been already asked but not exactly as I am going to do (or I haven't found it), about knowing when someone clicks into a cross domain iframe on which I have no control.
I have seen there are some tricks to get it: I do that, and it works  on FF, IE 11 and Chrome, listening to a focusout() event; anyway it works only the first time someone clicks on the iframe.
Now, to know if the user clicks again, when this event happens, I have tried to get back the focus on an element inside the body of my document, but this doesn't work.
Here is the code I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <title>Focus() test</title>

        <!-- JQuery libraries -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" id="myInput" value=""> <br />

        <div id="iframeContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 280px">
            <iframe id="theIframe" height="400px" width="280px" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=0B3R3uQMMhRrxUFJyYllhd0hVSkk&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true"> </iframe>
        </div>

        <script>

            var clickNum = 0;

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myInput").focus();
                $("body").focusout(function() {
                    clickNum++;
                    alert("click num:" + clickNum);
                    $("#myInput").focus();
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I also tried substituting the last line of jQuery code i.e.

```
$("#myInput").focus();
```

with several instances of:

```
$(this).next().focus();
```

trying to simulate the tab key.
As a matter of fact, when someone clicks in the iframe (in my code on one of the zoom control of Google Drive preview), the focus is lost by the body and the alert is fired, but then I can't get back the focus on, for example, the input field.
But if someone press the tab key for a certain number of times (it depends on which zoom control one has previously clicked and with which order) the focus is back on the input field, or obviously, directly if someone clicks inside it.
Then if someone clicks again on one zoom control, the alert is fired again and you can trace the number of clicks.
So my final question is:
**Is there a way to get back the focus from a cross domain iframe once the focus has gone on it or, when you can't control both documents in cross domains as in my case, you don't have any hope to get it back?**
 
I know that these things have been maybe already asked, but I just found pieces of my whole question and not always with the exact same context. 
Thank you in advance,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
*(Look at history for the previous answer)*

Based on your last comment, indicating what you really intend to do with the `iframe`...
You can use the "iframe mask" I previously suggested in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Onload input focus.
  $("#myInput").focus();

  // iframe mask creation
  var iframe = $("#iframeContainer");
  var maskCSS = {
    height:iframe.height(),
    width: iframe.width(),
    top: iframe.offset().top,
    left: iframe.offset().left,
    "z-index":999999,
    position:"absolute",
    "background-color":"red", // You may remove color and opacity. ;)
    "opacity":0.4
  };

  var mask = $("<div>").css(maskCSS).attr("id","iframeMask");
  $("body").append(mask);
  //console.log(maskCSS);

  //
  // --------- Click handlers in/out the iframe
  //

  // Detect a click in the iframe (specifically: on the mask!)
  $("#iframeMask").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Click detected on the iframe mask. => Remove the mask and resize the iframe.");

    $(this).css({"z-index":-1});
    $("#iframeContainer, #theIframe").css({"width":560,"height":800});
  });


  // Detect a click out the iframe
  $("body").not("#iframeMask").on("click",function(e){

    if( $(e.target).attr("id") != "iframeMask" ){
      console.log("Click detected on the main document. => Reset iframe original size.");

      $("#iframeMask").css({"z-index":999999});
      $("#iframeContainer, #theIframe").css({"width":280,"height":400});
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" value=""> <br />

<div id="iframeContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 280px">
  <iframe id="theIframe" height="400px" width="280px" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=0B3R3uQMMhRrxUFJyYllhd0hVSkk&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true"> </iframe>
</div>
```

**So if you ran the snippet above** (preferably in full page mode), you saw that an iframe resize and reset back to initial size is possible...

It isn't possible to access the `iframe` inner elements...
From what I know, it is impossible at all.
But your intend is only to control the container size, so this is possible and here is how I did:

1. Create a mask above the `iframe` to detect user focus.

On user click on the mask:

2. Immediately move this mask below the `iframe` in order to allow user to click inside it.
3. By the way, change the `iframe` container properties as you whish.
   You even can use an animation for more smoothness!

On user click outside the `iframe`:

4. Reset the `iframe` to its original size (if you wish, this is not mandatory).
5. Replace the mask above the `iframe` for future click detection.

The mask in the snippet above is red with 40% opacity...
But if it is invisible, it will look like magic!
;)

Comment: @ Louys     Thank you but I am trying to fire an action when a user clicks on a zoom control of the Google pdf preview inside the iframe. I wish to resize the div container and the iframe on these actions. Everything is possible, but I can't trace the click events on the iframe (except the first one). I know there are issues related to security reasons, but I hoped someone knows if there is a way to just get back the focus or it is definetively impossible to do. Thank you anyway

Comment: I got it! And I improved my answer. Have a look! ;)

Comment: Hi Louys, thanks for your effort, but also this time your code is not doing what I was wondering if it were possible. I wanted that the focus could go back to the input field via code, so not relying on a user action (click or whatelse). I was trying to catch when a user clicks --consecutively-- inside the cross domain iframe. Anyway at the moment I have abandoned this way, as I supposed is not possible and I have also noticed other problems with Google preview. I have started watching to the Pdf.js project, even if also that way is not smooth :-( . I have opened a new help request for that.Tx